# multiple loops to check booleans in javascript

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have a button that's hidden until a condition is true

to check this, it has to look through a list (someList) to find any and all items that have needsApproval: true

then it checks in another array of items (data) to see if they're active

if everything is active we can show the button

is there a better way more modern way of doing this without multiple loops seems very inefficient?

```
const someList = [
    { id: 1, sid: 'a', needsApproval: true},
    { id: 2, sid: 'b',  needsApproval: true},
    { id: 3, sid: 'c',  needsApproval: false},
  { id: 4, sid: 'd',  needsApproval: false}
]

const data = [
    { id: 1, sid: 'a', active: true},
    { id: 2, sid: 'b', active: false},
]


    const needsApproval = someList.filter(x => x.needsApproval === true)
    needsApproval.forEach(a => {
        const found = data.find(s => s.sid === a.sid)
        if (found && found.active === false) return false
    })

    return true
```

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's not appropriate for Stack Overflow and belongs on https://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: @ScottMarcus It doesn't work, so it's not appropriate for CR.

Comment: @Barmar The OP doesn't say it doesn't work - - only asks if there is another way because this seems inefficient.

Comment: @ScottMarcus If you read the code you'll see that it can't work. `checkButton()` always returns `true` unconditionally.

Comment: @ScottMarcus ... and clearly `const found = data.find.sid === a.sid` is not correct

Comment: I removed the function

Comment: I didn't read the code because the question didn't say that it was not working, nor ask for help making it work.  As I said, the question asks for a better way to implement it (more modern, less loops).

Answer (score 1):

You're returning `false` from the `forEach` callback function, not from `checkButton`. `forEach` doesn't do anything with the return values of its function. So your `checkButton()` function always returns `true`.

You can use `every()` to check whether a condition is true for all elements of an array.

```js
const someList = [
    { id: 1, sid: 'a', needsApproval: true},
    { id: 2, sid: 'b',  needsApproval: true},
    { id: 3, sid: 'c',  needsApproval: false},
  { id: 4, sid: 'd',  needsApproval: false}
]

const data = [
    { id: 1, sid: 'a', active: true},
    { id: 2, sid: 'b', active: false},
]

const checkButton = () => {
  const needsApproval = someList.filter(x => x.needsApproval === true);
  return needsApproval.every(a => {
    const found = data.find(x => x.sid === a.sid);
    return !(found && found.active === false);
  });
}

console.log(checkButton());
```

Comment: I am kind of surprised I haven't come across every() before.

Comment: I guess I was looking for every()

what does return adding the ! in !(found && found.active === false); do?

Comment: It returns `false` when `(found && found.active === false)` is true, and returns `true` when it's false.

Comment: can we just return (found && found.active)?

Comment: I was basing my code on the logic in your original code. When the element is not found, you return true, not false.